# Is NFS a protocol or a program?

Tags: nfs

For example . HTTP is a protocol. Client applications are Browsers and Server application can be Apache . Both client and server application communicate via the HTTP protocol .
Now is NFS(network file system) a protocol or an application.
If it is a protocol then what are the applications (programs) that should be installed on server and client which will use this protocol to share files .
Or is it the name given to a set of applications ? Like nfs-common , nfs-server-kernel and portmap

Comment: "Network File System (NFS) is a distributed file system protocol" [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System)

Comment: It's a protocol. Linux has a in-kernel implementation of both a client and a server for NFS. But even with a in-kernel NFS, there are functions delegated to userland programs (`rpc.mountd`, `rpc.idmapd`, etc). Please narrow your Q to something that could be answered punctually.

Answer (score 2):

NFS is a protocol developed by Sun. There are multiple implementations of the protocol for the server and client component. The implementation of NFS in the linux kernel is served by multiple developers. Have a look at http://nfs.sourceforge.net/